# wireless stopped working after update ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but wired connection still working

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Please help me what I have to do to inform for my system condition to solve the problem with wireless.

Comment: **Note:** If you *updated to* **12.04 LTS**, then the previous OS and upgrade path are *no longer supported*. Treat this as a NEW install of 12.04 LTS, and do basic Wi-Fi troubleshooting. What does the output of **`lsusb`** or **`sudo lshw`** identify the Wi-Fi chipset as? --- **NOTE**: *You should really do a NEW clean install of **14.04 LTS**, after backing up you data and settings.*